# how to get particular object from array of data in firebase database java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

in my Firebase RealTime Database i have table `bookings`, with data like,

```
 "booking_id1": [
   {
      "id":"1","name":"ram"
    },{
       "id":"2","name":"raj"
    },{
       "id":"3","name":"ramraj"
    }
  ],
"booking_id2": [
   {
      "id":"4","name":"ram"
    },{
       "id":"5","name":"raj"
    },{
       "id":"6","name":"ramraj"
    }
  ]
```

now if i use like

```
Firebase.database().ref('/bookings').once("value", snapshot => {
});
```

it results all the data like,

```
 {
    "booking_id1": [
   {
      "id":"1","name":"ram"
    },{
       "id":"2","name":"raj"
    },{
       "id":"3","name":"ramraj"
    }
  ],
"booking_id2": [
   {
      "id":"4","name":"ram"
    },{
       "id":"5","name":"raj"
    },{
       "id":"6","name":"ramraj"
    }
  ]
 }
```

But i want to get object with `id=4` only. like,

```
{
"booking_id2": [
   {
      "id":"4","name":"ram"
    },{
       "id":"5","name":"raj"
    },{
       "id":"6","name":"ramraj"
    }
  ]
}
```

any suggestion will be helpful... Thank you

Comment: @DacreDenny 1>`performing the field based filter client side after fetching a list of documents from firebase` will take much load for mobile app side(currently using the same) app may hang if bulk amount of data.
2>`fetch a document by it's id` means `booking_id` did you mean? if so, `booking_id` unknown while requesting...

Comment: yes the document id / `booking_id`